# Allowing a child Iframe to call a function on its parent window from a different domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have made a page which gets loaded in an IFrame and it needs to call a function on the parent page after it finishes loading.

It works locally in development (on the same domain) but in the Real World it is hosted on a completely different domain, so obviously I am running into Cross domain problems, ie:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://[...]site1.com from frame with URL http://[...]site2.com/iframe. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I control both the servers, so is it possible for me to put something on one or both of the servers that says they're allowed to talk to each other?

I have looked at setting "document.domain" in both the Iframe page and the parent page.

I have experimented with setting the Access Control Header:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

But neither of those work.

Is there any way of allowing an Iframe calling a function in the Parent window on a completely different domain when I control both servers?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477324/iframe-calling-parent-javascript) provides an extremely simple solution.

Comment: @craned but the post only works for the same domain

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can communicate between frames via the [message posting API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

For example, in your child frame you might call:

```
parent.postMessage("child frame", "*");
```

And in the parent frame, register a message handler:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    console.log("Hello from " + event.data);
});
```

Comment: Tested on the IE11

Comment: To get the output of the function, you would also need to [send a message back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56153777/975097) to the child frame.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options here: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: although there is a note at the top that this article is mainly kept for historical purposes and in the modern world you should only be using `postMessage` (as per the accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be easily solved by using an **.htaccess** rewrite.

Demo:

A. Create a directory named "iframeContent/" on SERVER 1.

B. Place in that directory a file named index.php containing:

> ```
> <html> 
> <head></head> 
> <body>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>     parent.check();
>
> </script>
>
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```

This is the content of the iFrame. It will call a function in a parent.

C. Create a directory named "iframeTesting_without-htaccess/" on SERVER 2.

D. Place in that directory a file named index.php containing:

> ```
> <html> 
> <head></head> 
> <body>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>     function check() { 
>
>        alert("hello");
>
>     }
>
> </script>
>
> <iframe id="sidebnrId" name="sidebnr"
> src="PATH-ON-SERVER-1/iframeContent/" frameborder="0"
> height="500px" width="600px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
>
> </script>
>
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```

This is simply the content of the parent windows. Just note that the iFrame content is located on another server (because on SERVER 1).

E. Access "PATH-ON-SERVER-2/iframeTesting_without-htaccess/" with a web-browser -> nothing happens: the iframe does not have access to the function of its parent.

**HERE IS HOW YOU CAN SOLVE THE PROBLEM**

F. Create another directory named "iframeTesting_with-htaccess/" on SERVER 2.

G. Place in that directory a file named index.php containing:

> ```
> <html> 
> <head></head> 
> <body>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>     function check() { 
>
>        alert("hello");
>
>     }
>
> </script>
>
> <iframe id="sidebnrId" name="sidebnr"
> src="content-iframe/" frameborder="0"
> height="500px" width="600px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
>
> </script>
>
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```

This time the iFrame does not point anymore directly to the content on SERVER 1 but to an intermediate fictive directory "content-iframe/" located on the same server (SERVER 2).

H. Place in that directory a .htaccess file containing:

> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^content-iframe/$ PATH-ON-SERVER-1/iframeContent/ [R,NC,P]
> ```

The role of that file is to redirect any access to the fictive directory to the content on the SERVER 1.

I. Try again, access "PATH-ON-SERVER-2/iframeTesting_with-htaccess/" with a web-browser. This time it will work. I hope it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, you can use [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate between cooperating frames on different domains.  You can't call a function directly, but you can pass data or messages between the two.  See the [description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).