# How to pass a variable from one frame to another frame in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink, frames

Let's say I declared  the variable `var = 5;` in *frame1*. Now how do I pass this variable to *frame2*? I'd like to pass it using a hyperlink. Are there any other ways to do that?

Also, how do I access that variable after passing to *frame2* in *frame2*?

Comment: <a href="getValue.html" target= "frame2">CLICK  HERE TO PASS THE VALUE TO FRAME2</a>

Comment: Older post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042615/allowing-a-child-iframe-to-call-a-function-on-its-parent-window-from-a-different) might be helpful

Comment: can we pass variables that way, using parent.postMessage()?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query string. You could set the link in JavaScript like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('linkId');
a.href = "link?var=" + var;
```

You would have to run this code each time you change your variable.

If you need to parse the query string I would refer to this post:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: How to access this variable in frame2?

Comment: Edited my answer to include a way to change the link dynamically